# Wordpress / Learndash - Send email when a comment is added

Tags: php, wordpress

I use Learndash to create courses. I have different courses and different topics and lessons which are like: Courses: Physics, Lessons: Serie 1, Topics: Exercice 1, Exercice 2, Exercice 3,...
Each courses has multiple series and each series has multiple exercises.
I have also different teacher for each Courses and I would like to know how is it possible to send them e-mail when a student comment on their Courses ?
I found out how to send email using `wp_mail()` function and how to trigger when user send a comment: `wp_insert_comment`. But I can't find how I can get only comment in one course.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress by default provides the functionality to send email to site administrator and post author when a comment is added.

I would recommend you to go through this blog as it provide step by step instructions for the same
https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-manage-wordpress-comment-notification-emails/

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I also use the plugin notifications which is used in this part of the website: Creating Custom Comment Notification in WordPress. I can setup notification when a course is commented. Now I need to know how can I know which course has been commented ? fe. If someone comment into maths lesson, I only want to send email to maths teacher.
I also forgot to mention but the teacher isn't the post author.

Comment: You will have to do custom development for it .

Comment: I know and that's what I was looking first. but as I said, I can't find a way to get the course title through topics with some php request. My logic is if $course_title contains "physics", then send email to physics teacher. I know `strpos()`function in php and I can use it to get my condition.

Comment: Are the details of teacher i.e. email address and name stored as meta data of course in wordpress DB? Because you will need the same as well to write the logic of sending email to intended teachers. The logic would be as below:
1) Hook into wp_insert_comment
2) Determine the course category i.e. physics, maths etc
3) Send email using the metadata of course i.e. teacher email address (if it is stored in DB otherwise you will need to do that for all courses first)

It would be a custom development with intermediate knowledge required of wordpress and php

Comment: there's no meta data in course, but I know which teacher has which courses, so with a lot of if conditions I can repeat the same thing for one: `wp_mail(« Teacher's mail », « New comment has been added », $comment_data->comment_content);` I can get comment data with the `wp_insert_comment` hook or if this doesn't work, it's not necessary. We just need to notify the teacher that a comment has been added on his course.